# TYPO3, looped DB changes while trying to add a key to other table

Tags: typo3, ddl

I'm extending ext:DAM in my custom extension (as usually, to keep the DAM sources unchanged) and one of task is adding a fields to `tx_dam` table. In my `ext_tables.sql` file I added (shortened):

```
CREATE TABLE tx_dam (
  # other fields
  direct_download tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

  KEY file_path (file_path)
);
```

and DB compare tool adds new fields as required and there's nor any problem, but every time when I'm running Compare tool (or updating DB from EM)  it wants to drop and recreate the `file_path` key, just in one step:

```
ALTER TABLE tx_dam DROP KEY file_path;
ALTER TABLE tx_dam ADD KEY file_path (file_path);
```

Why is that? Is that some kind of bug, or creating keys is possible only from within the original `ext_tables.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 just supports a subset of SQL. The DB compare check against the field definition of the DB. If the returned string does not match the expected value, it is considered to need modification.

Try to remove the space before the parenthesis.

If this does not help, then you will need to figure out how your database returns the key information.

Comment: The MySQL sets index's `sub_part` for this field to 333 as it's `varchar(4000)` adding index with `KEY file_path (file_path(333))` avoids dropping of the index